# How to destroy slider vue-awesome-swiper in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, swiper.js

I need to destroy vue-awesome-swiper on desktop and leave on tablet screen. exactly destroy, and not disable swipe. But can I destroy swiper? In directive :options I pass params and component-tag swiper will be worked in any case. Only without passed params

```
   <template lang="pug">
    .app
      swiper(:options="swiperOptions")
        swiper-slide(
          v-for="(slide, idx) in slides"
          :key="idx"
          )

    <script>

    import { swiper, swiperSlide } from 'vue-awesome-swiper'

    export default {
      name: 'MySlider',
      components: {
        swiper,
        swiperSlide
      },
      data() {
        return {
          slides: [
            {
              title: 'Заголовок 1',
              img: 'title.jpg',
            },
            {
              title: 'title2',
              img: 'slide2.jpg',
            },
            {
              title: 'title3',
              img: 'slide3.jpg',
            }
        ],
          swiperOptions: {
            slidesPerView: 5,
            spaceBetween: 21,
            // allowTouchMove: false,
            breakpoints: {
              992: {
                slidesPerView: 3,
                spaceBetween: 25,
              },
              768: {
                slidesPerView: 3.7,
                spaceBetween: 22,
              },
              640: {
                slidesPerView: 2.2,
                spaceBetween: 15,
                initialSlide: 0,
                centeredSlides: false,
              }
            },
          },
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using v-if on `swiper` element so it won't be rendered when viewed on desktop?

You would create a method that detects if the client is desktop or tablet and pass the result to the `v-if` attribute.

Comment: Hi! Yes, I tried. But in that case "swiper-slide" will be hide, because  it's inside the swiper

Comment: Then I think you could only disable the swipe as long as swiper-slide is inside the swiper.

Comment: What about creating another element without swiper? You would use this element only for tablet.

Comment: Yes. I think this more suitable solution. To create another element without swiper. Thank you very much!